# Elasticsearch - Highlight of Wildcard Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have found a behaviour of highlight of wildcard little different.
When I search using single "*" i.e., a wildcard character, It does not highlight any of the values.
But if I do the same using two or more "*" i.e., wildcard character, It does highlight all the values. 
Although the results fetched are the same, why is there such a difference in highlight?
example :

## 1. Multiple wildcards

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "ID"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "**",
                  "fields": [
                    "ID"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": "unified",
    "fragment_size": 0,
    "order": "score",
    "number_of_fragments": 4,
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Results :

```
{
  "_index": "index_name",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "AUTO",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "ID": "AUTO"
  },
  "highlight": {
    "ID": [
      "<em>AUTO</em>"
    ]
  }
}
```

## 2. Singular Wildcard:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "ID"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*",
                  "fields": [
                    "ID"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": "unified",
    "fragment_size": 0,
    "order": "score",
    "number_of_fragments": 4,
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Results :

```
{
  "_index": "index_name",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "AUTO",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "ID": "AUTO"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a direct answer to your question about why these queries behave different. But you can use a wildcard query instead.

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "ID"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "ID": "*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": "unified",
    "fragment_size": 0,
    "order": "score",
    "number_of_fragments": 4,
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [the documentation of Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). There is:

> Pure wildcards `\*` are rewritten to [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-exists-query.html) queries for efficiency. As a
>   consequence, the wildcard `"field:*"` would match documents with an
>   empty value like the following: `{ "field": "" }` ... and would
>   not match if the field is missing or set with an explicit null value
>   like the following: `{ "field": null }`

So I'm guessing singular `*` is treated in some special way because of this.